# From Sharepoint Designer 2010, is it possible to create an html/jquery form and send data to another server?

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am in process of learning how to create a basic SharePoint HTMLform from SharePoint Designer 2010.  I need to have this form avialable to the public on a .aspx page.  Can I customize the layout?  On submit, send the form data to another server.  The data does not need to be saved to my current server. Can all this be accomplished from within SharePoint Designer 2010? If so, what would be a starting tuturial for this process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it. It's not the most elegant, but doable. Through SharePoint Designer, create your custom HTML form on an .HTML page.  If it involves javaScript or a posting data to another URL, place the appropriate code on the same page.  Save it.  Then on your publishing .aspx page which will have a  web part, load a Page Viewer to call the custom HTML form you just created.  If you need additional JavaScript to modify the form after the DOM is ready, jQuery is excellent for the job.